# Is there any way to test in-app purchases without submitting to windows store?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

We are developing a whitelabel solution for our client, but we need to test various in-app purchase methods before we can continue. We know about the CurrentAppSimulator, but since we need to verify the receipts on the server side (so we need to talk to MS servers for this), we can't use it. Also, the server is not done by us but the client himself.

Since there is no test-drive for Windows Store apps we are kind of stuck here. There is just no way we can test this, or is there?

Comment: Same question, there's also an example there:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985618/how-do-we-verify-windows-8-in-app-billing-receipt-on-the-server-side